# Можно просто "ломиться"? Без указания куда / от чего / от кого?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Обо мне начали говорить, поэтому и на предпоказах – на прогонах
>   экзамена, и на самом показе зал буквально ломился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подборка примеров из Нацкорпуса (просто ломиться):

Поэтические вечера собирали сотни людей, залы **ломились**, когда приезжали гости из Москвы и Питера. [Анатолий Кирилин. Мой брошенный дом // «Сибирские огни», 2012]

Клуб был уж полон, столы **ломились**, вспышки сверкали, но напрасно: главный герой презентации "Московских окон", нового многосерийного художественного фильма телекомпании РТР, задерживался. [Анна Ковалева. Про доброе и светлое. Снят многосерийный сиквел «Покровских ворот» (2001) // «Известия», 2001.10.26]

А все одно, не вывезли хлеба! Амбары **ломились**. От изобилия завелись в подполах мышата невиданные, хольные, злые. [Герман Садулаев. Таблетка (2008)]

А меня, как нарочно, оставили в покое на три месяца. Закрома **ломились**. Как скряга, я складывал сэкономленные куски хлеба в кирпичики-буханки ― их получалось четырнадцать с половиной. [Михаил Елизаров. Библиотекарь (2007)]

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что так можно говорить:  зал буквально ломился.

**ломи́ться**
II несов. неперех. разг.; безл.
Находиться во множестве, быть переполненным чем-либо.
[**Толковый словарь Ефремовой**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/182333/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

*Главными на ярмарке были купцы, торговавшие шерстью, – от мелких торговцев, скупавших товар у крестьян, до крупных дельцов, таких как Эдмунд, у которого **склады просто ломились.***
К. Фоллетт. Мир без конца

**Сундуки ломятся**
*у кого.* Волг. О человеке, живущем в достатке.
Большой словарь русских поговорок

Здесь можно провести аналогию: сундук ломится — переполнен товарами, вещами, а зал ломится — переполнен зрителями, посетителями.

***Зал буквально ломится*** (а значит, не менее полутора тысяч).
[**В. А. Успенский. Колмогоров, каким я его помню**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=iVfpCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA299&lpg=PA299&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=QrK7mfmtRb&sig=aExS5yFB1aCkK_S_Gdvh_JaC9d0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCr5DImZTYAhUDa1AKHUC2BG8Q6AEISDAK#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false)

*Я видел, как на показах действительно **ломятся залы**, как люди не могут попасть, как они заранее покупают билеты.*
И. Твердовский (из интервью)